# "Flattening" a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

So my aim is to go from:

```
fruitColourMapping = [{'apple': 'red'}, {'banana': 'yellow'}]
```

to

```
finalMap = {'apple': 'red', 'banana': 'yellow'}
```

A way I got is:

```
 from itertools import chain
 fruits = list(chain.from_iterable([d.keys() for d in fruitColourMapping]))
 colour = list(chain.from_iterable([d.values() for d in fruitColourMapping]))
 return dict(zip(fruits, colour))
```

Is there any better more pythonic way?

Comment: FYI, you really don't want to do it this way.  Dictionaries are intrinsically unordered, so it is only a matter of luck that iterating over the dictionary twice (as you do to build the `fruit` and `color` lists) generates 2 sets of values in the correct order.

Comment: @sr2222 not true. The documentation [explicitly states](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dict#dictionary-view-objects) that if you iterate over keys and values without mutating the dictionary in the meantime, the order is guaranteed to correspond.

Comment: @DanielRoseman It's still not a good habit to get in to though.  It won't be thread safe if that ever becomes a concern, and just because something implements the same interface as a dictionary doesn't mean it will behave exactly like a dictionary in these sorts of details.  It's the kind of thing that works fine until it doesn't, and then you get subtle hard to track down bugs.  It's easy enough to avoid, so you might as well do so.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
finalMap = {}
for d in fruitColourMapping:
    finalMap.update(d)
```

Comment: Just curious: should it work if one of 'd's is {'apple': 'red', 'orange': 'orange'}?

Comment: This code will simply add all dictionary entries to `finalMap`, so it will add both `apple` and `orange` keys.

Comment: And when moving beyond simple examples, make sure all the keys are globally unique because `update` (or any method that ends with a single dict) will deduplicate the keys. If you need all the duplicates (e.g. when all dicts have the same keys), convert the dicts to pandas DataFrames before concatenating.

Answer (score 43):

### Why copy at all?

In Python 3, you can use the new [`ChainMap`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/collections#collections.ChainMap):

> **A ChainMap groups multiple dicts (or other mappings) together to create a single, updateable view.**
>   The underlying mappings are stored in a list.  That list is public and
>   can    accessed or updated using the *maps* attribute.  There is no
>   other state.     Lookups search the underlying mappings successively
>   until a key is found.    In contrast, writes, updates, and deletions
>   only operate on the first    mapping.

All you need is this (*do* change the names to abide by [Python naming conventions](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions)):

```
from collections import ChainMap
fruit_colour_mapping = [{'apple': 'red'}, {'banana': 'yellow'}]
final_map = ChainMap(*fruit_colour_mapping)
```

And then you can use all the normal mapping operations:

```
# print key value pairs:
for element in final_map.items():
    print(element)

# change a value:
final_map['banana'] = 'green'    # supermarkets these days....

# access by key:
print(final_map['banana'])
```

Comment: +1 I think this is one of the cooler `dict` additions in python 3. First saw this in the new `Python Cookbook`.

Comment: search operation of ChainMap is much slower than Python dictionary. You should convert to final_map to a Python dictionary.

Answer (score 36):

```
{k: v for d in fruitColourMapping for k, v in d.items()}
```

Answer (score 14):

Rather than deconstructing and reconstructing, just copy and update:

```
final_map = {}
for fruit_color_definition in fruit_color_mapping:
    final_map.update(fruit_color_definition)
```

Answer (score 6):

```
dict(d.items()[0] for d in fruitColourMapping)
```

Answer (score 6):

## Approach

Use [reduce](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) to apply each dict to an empty initializer. Since `dict.update` always returns `None`, use `d.update(src) or d` to give `reduce` the desired return value.

## Code

```
final_dict = reduce(lambda d, src: d.update(src) or d, dicts, {})
```

## Test

```
>>> dicts = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'b': 3, 'c': 4}, {'a': 6}]
>>> final_dict = reduce(lambda d, src: d.update(src) or d, dicts, {})
>>> final_dict
{'a': 6, 'c': 4, 'b': 3}
```

Comment: In order to feel a less hacky, you might consider using the new dict merging syntax with the overload of the OR operator: `final_dict = reduce(lambda x, y: x | y, dicts, {})`

Comment: @NeiNeto your comment is anachronistic. When I wrote this in 2013, the latest python was 3.3.0. The feature you suggest I ought to have written about would not exist for several more years.

Comment: Indeed. Quite the bruh moment. Fortunately for the achronicity of my comment, the "you" I'm referring to is the reader rather than you, Hugh. Btw, nice word of the day that one, felt like something straight from vsauce. Would you consider editing your answer, though?

Answer (score 5):

**Given**

```
d1, d2 = [{'apple': 'red'}, {'banana': 'yellow'}]
```

**Code**

In Python 3.5, dictionary unpacking was introduced (see [PEP 448](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/)):

```
{**d1, **d2}
# {'apple': 'red', 'banana': 'yellow'}
```

In Python 3.9, the [merge operator](https://docs.python.org/3.9/whatsnew/3.9.html#dictionary-merge-update-operators) was introduced:

```
d1 | d2
# {'apple': 'red', 'banana': 'yellow'}
```

Answer (score 5):

I came up with a interesting one liner.

```py
>>> a = [{"wow": 1}, {"ok": 2}, {"yeah": 3}, {"ok": [1,2,3], "yeah": True}]
>>> a = dict(sum(map(list, map(dict.items, a)), []))
>>> a
{'wow': 1, 'ok': [1, 2, 3], 'yeah': True}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also try:

`finalMap = dict(item for mapping in fruitColourMapping for item in mapping.items())`