# Merging list of python dictionaries

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have got 2 list of dictionary I would like to merge:

```
 l1 =[{'a':1},{'b':2},{'c':3}]
 l2 =[{'d':4},{'e':5},{'f':6}]
```

I have done this:

```
l1.append(l2.copy())
```

The result is merging the list : `[{'a': 1}, {'b': 2}, {'c': 3}, [{'d': 4}, {'e': 5}, {'f': 6}]]`

instead what I am looking for though is to have this: `[{'a': 1}, {'b': 2}, {'c': 3}, {'d': 4}, {'e': 5}, {'f': 6}]`

Any idea how to perform is welcomed.

Comment: `l3 = l1 + l2`, or, `l1.extend(l2)` for in-place (modifies `l1`).

Comment: Duplicate post, see [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15647690/flattening-a-list-of-dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15647690/flattening-a-list-of-dictionaries)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply add both the lists as below:

```
>>> l1+l2
[{'a': 1}, {'b': 2}, {'c': 3}, {'d': 4}, {'e': 5}, {'f': 6}]
```

Or

```
>>> l1.extend(l2)
>>> l1
[{'a': 1}, {'b': 2}, {'c': 3}, [{'d': 4}, {'e': 5}, {'f': 6}]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

`l3 = [*l1, *l2]`

result: `[{'a': 1}, {'b': 2}, {'c': 3}, {'d': 4}, {'e': 5}, {'f': 6}]`

Answer (score 0):

Since `l2,l1` are lists, you can unpack them in `l3`

```
l1 =[{'a':1},{'b':2},{'c':3}]
l2 =[{'d':4},{'e':5},{'f':6}]
l3=[*l1,*l2]
print(l3)
```